# Error in Grid magento 2 Fatal error: Method Magento\Ui\TemplateEngine\Xhtml\Result::__toString()

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1

I have created magento 2 module with single table that and trying to create admin grid with that module but i am getting below error

> Fatal error: Method
>   Magento\Ui\TemplateEngine\Xhtml\Result::__toString() must not throw an
>   exception, caught TypeError: Argument 5 passed to
>   Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\Collection\AbstractCollection::__construct()
>   must implement interface
>   Magento\Framework\DB\Adapter\AdapterInterface, instance of
>   Magento\Store\Model\StoreManager given, called in
>   D:\wamp64\www\magento2\app\code\Vendor\Module\Model\ResourceModel\Modelname\Grid\Collection.php
>   on line 55 in
>   D:\wamp64\www\magento2\vendor\magento\module-ui\Component\Wrapper\UiComponent.php
>   on line 0

Here is my collection code

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Model\ResourceModel\Sample\Grid;

use Magento\Framework\Api\Search\SearchResultInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Api\Search\AggregationInterface;
use Vendor\Module\Model\ResourceModel\Sample\Collection as SampleCollection;

class Collection extends SampleCollection implements SearchResultInterface
{
    /**
     * @var AggregationInterface
     */
    protected $aggregations;

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Data\Collection\EntityFactoryInterface $entityFactory
     * @param \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Data\Collection\Db\FetchStrategyInterface $fetchStrategy
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Event\ManagerInterface $eventManager
     * @param \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager
     * @param \Magento\Framework\EntityManager\MetadataPool $metadataPool
     * @param mixed|null $mainTable
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\AbstractDb $eventPrefix
     * @param mixed $eventObject
     * @param mixed $resourceModel
     * @param string $model
     * @param null $connection
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\AbstractDb|null $resource
     *
     * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.ExcessiveParameterList)
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\Data\Collection\EntityFactoryInterface $entityFactory,
        \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger,
        \Magento\Framework\Data\Collection\Db\FetchStrategyInterface $fetchStrategy,
        \Magento\Framework\Event\ManagerInterface $eventManager,
        \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
        \Magento\Framework\EntityManager\MetadataPool $metadataPool,
        $mainTable,
        $eventPrefix,
        $eventObject,
        $resourceModel,
        $model = 'Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\Document',
        $connection = null,
        \Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\AbstractDb $resource = null
    ) {
        parent::__construct(
            $entityFactory,
            $logger,
            $fetchStrategy,
            $eventManager,
            $storeManager,
            $metadataPool,
            $connection,
            $resource
        );
        $this->_eventPrefix = $eventPrefix;
        $this->_eventObject = $eventObject;
        $this->_init($model, $resourceModel);
        $this->setMainTable($mainTable);
    }

    /**
     * @return AggregationInterface
     */
    public function getAggregations()
    {
        return $this->aggregations;
    }

    /**
     * @param AggregationInterface $aggregations
     * @return $this
     */
    public function setAggregations($aggregations)
    {
        $this->aggregations = $aggregations;
    }

    /**
     * Get search criteria.
     *
     * @return \Magento\Framework\Api\SearchCriteriaInterface|null
     */
    public function getSearchCriteria()
    {
        return null;
    }

    /**
     * Set search criteria.
     *
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Api\SearchCriteriaInterface $searchCriteria
     * @return $this
     * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.UnusedFormalParameter)
     */
    public function setSearchCriteria(\Magento\Framework\Api\SearchCriteriaInterface $searchCriteria = null)
    {
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get total count.
     *
     * @return int
     */
    public function getTotalCount()
    {
        return $this->getSize();
    }

    /**
     * Set total count.
     *
     * @param int $totalCount
     * @return $this
     * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.UnusedFormalParameter)
     */
    public function setTotalCount($totalCount)
    {
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Set items list.
     *
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Api\ExtensibleDataInterface[] $items
     * @return $this
     * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.UnusedFormalParameter)
     */
    public function setItems(array $items = null)
    {
        return $this;
    }
}
```

Vendor\Module\Model\ResourceModel\Sample\Collection.php

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Model\ResourceModel\Sample;
class Collection extends \Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\Collection\AbstractCollection
{
    protected function _construct()
    {
        $this->_init('Vendor\Module\Model\Sample','Vendor\Module\Model\ResourceModel\Sample');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is the order of the parameters in your `parent::__construct()` call.
the class your are extending does not have a constructor so it the parent of the parent constructor will be called.
And this parent of parent is `\Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\Collection\AbstractCollection`.

It's constructor looks like this:

```
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\Data\Collection\EntityFactoryInterface $entityFactory,
    \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger,
    \Magento\Framework\Data\Collection\Db\FetchStrategyInterface $fetchStrategy,
    \Magento\Framework\Event\ManagerInterface $eventManager,
    \Magento\Framework\DB\Adapter\AdapterInterface $connection = null,
    \Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\AbstractDb $resource = null
) {
    $this->_eventManager = $eventManager;
    parent::__construct($entityFactory, $logger, $fetchStrategy, $connection);
    $this->_construct();
    $this->_resource = $resource;
    $this->setConnection($this->getResource()->getConnection());
    $this->_initSelect();
}
```

so the 5th parameter must be something that implements `\Magento\Framework\DB\Adapter\AdapterInterface`.
In your case, the 5th parameter is something that implementes `\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface`.

Change your `parent::__construct()` call to this:

```
    parent::__construct(
        $entityFactory,
        $logger,
        $fetchStrategy,
        $eventManager,
        $connection,
        $resource
    );
```

the parameters `$storeManager` and `$metadataPool` are not part of the classes you extend. If you need them in your own class you can add them in the `__construct`  method like this:

```
$this->storeManager = $storeManager;
$this->metadataPool = $metadataPool;
```

and declare them as protected members as you did for `$aggregations`.

Comment: Hi @Marius, If I extends \Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Collection\AbstractCollection then, what should I need to change in construct ?

Comment: Current, I get error Fatal error: Method Magento\Ui\TemplateEngine\Xhtml\Result::__toString() must not throw an exception, caught TypeError: Argument 5 passed to Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Collection\AbstractCollection::__construct() must be an instance of Magento\Eav\Model\Config, null given, called in /var/www/html/mg226/app/code/VendorName/ModuleName/Model/ResourceModel/Mainpage/Grid/Collection.php on line 80 in /var/www/html/mg226/vendor/magento/module-ui/Component/Wrapper/UiComponent.php on line 0

Comment: Perfect. It's working.