# Fatal error: Method Magento\Ui\TemplateEngine\Xhtml\Result::__toString() must not throw an exception

Tags: magento2, admin

When I open the category page on the admin and when I try to edit category I got the below error:

> Fatal error: Method
>   Magento\Ui\TemplateEngine\Xhtml\Result::__toString() must not throw an
>   exception, caught Error: Cannot use string offset as an array in
>   /vendor/magento/module-ui/Component/Wrapper/UiComponent.php on line 0

Do you have any idea how we can solve it!

Your answers are appreciated

Thanks!

Comment: here is [the solution](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/179747) which you faced the problem, might be helpful to you

Comment: Hi @Hit's I am not using the custom module I have an issue on the category section when I click on it.

Answer (score 1):

Just remove the generated folder.

In the magento root directory run this

> rm -rf generated/*